# More effective way to use pandas get_loc?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

**Task:** Search a multi column dataframe for a value (all values are unique) and return the index of that row.

**Currently:** using get_loc, but it only seems allow a pass of a single column at a time, resulting in quite a ineffective set of try except statements. Although it works is anyone aware of a more effective way to do this?

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
try: 
     unique_index = pd.Index(df['A'])
     print(unique_index.get_loc(20))
except KeyError:
    try: 
        unique_index = pd.Index(df['B'])
        print(unique_index.get_loc(20))
    except KeyError:
                unique_index = pd.Index(df['C'])
                print(unique_index.get_loc(20))
```

Loops don't seem to work because of the KeyError that is raised if a column doesn't contain a value. I've looked at functions such as .contains or .isin but it's the location index that i'm interested in.

Comment: in this example are you looking for the value 20 in the entire dataframe?

Comment: Yes, but since it's np.random.randint the value could be anything. Just an example i'm working with

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which returns a tuple of row and column indices where your value is present. You can then select just the row from this.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
indices = np.where(df.values == 20)
rows = indices[0]
if len(rows) != 0:
    print(rows[0])
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, although @piRiSquared answer is correct. This provides me with the exact result I need.

Answer (score 7):

Consider this example instead using `np.random.seed`

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(200 ,size=(4, 4)),
    columns=list('ABCD'))

df

     A    B    C    D
0   11   98  123   90
1  143  126   55  141
2  139  141  154  115
3   63  104  128  120
```

---

We can find where values are what you're looking for using `np.where` and slicing.  Notice that I used a value of `55` because that what I had in the data I got from the seed I chose.  This will work just fine for `20` if it is in your data set.  In fact, it'll work if you have more than one.

```
i, j = np.where(df.values == 55)
list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[j]))

[(1, 'C')]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use vectorized operations and boolean indexing:

```
df[(df==20).any(axis=1)].index
```

Comment: ah! that's two solutions I missed out on. you were faster ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since other posters used `np.where()` I'll give another option using [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html).

```
df.loc[df.isin([20]).any(axis=1)].index
```

Since `df.loc[*condition_here*]` will return TRUE if the condition is met, you can use `any` to filter to the row where it may be true

so here is my example of my df:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   82  7   48  90
1   68  18  90  14 #< ---- notice the 18 here
2   18  34  72  24 #< ---- notice the 18 here
3   69  73  40  86

df.isin([18])

    A   B   C   D
0   False   False   False   False
1   False   True    False   False  #<- ---- notice the TRUE value
2   True    False   False   False  #<- ---- notice the TRUE value
3   False   False   False   False


print(df.loc[df.isin([18]).any(axis=1)].index.tolist())
#output is a list
[1, 2]
```

Comment: @F.D, i added the output. I used `tolist()` to give you a list of the indices where the condition was met

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
df[df.eq(20)].stack()
Out[1220]: 
1  C    20.0
dtype: float64
```